# 10 $digest() iterations reached when using self-references in object literal declarations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm declaring an array as following:

```
vm.arr = [{
    type: {
        model: null,
        get constraints() {
            return MyFactory.buildTypeConstraints(this.model);
        } 
    },
    value: {
        model: null,
        get constraints() {
            return MyFactory.buildConstraints(this.model);
        } 
    },
    niveau: null
}];
```

And then in the html I'm looping this array :

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" ng-repeat="entry in controller.arr">
    <div class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <link link-model="entry.type.model" constraints="entry.type.constraints" flex-gt-sm "/>
    </div>
    <div class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <link link-model="entry.value.model" constraints="entry.value.constraints" flex-gt-sm "/>
    </div>

    <div class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <md-input-container>
            <rate ng-model="entry.niveau" allow-half-star="false" label="Niveau" />
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm getting this error :

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Which also says that the new value from `MyFactory.buildTypeConstraints(this.model)` is different from it's old value, even though that they are the same.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: where do you declare that array? do you do that inside of `$watch()`?

Comment: @skyboyer inside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

`MyFactory.buildTypeConstraints()` certainly returns new object instances.

Even if they are equal in value, they are not the same (they are different instances) so it triggers a new change detection and thus a new digest cycle.

Maybe you should use `angular.equals` to prevent the property returning a new object instance if no value has changed.

```
let typeConstaints, valueConstraints;
vm.arr = [{
    type: {
        model: null,
        get constraints() {
            let constr = MyFactory.buildTypeConstraints(this.model);
            if(!angular.equals(typeConstaints, constr)) typeConstaints = constr;
            return typeConstaints;
        } 
    },
    value: {
        model: null,
        get constraints() {
            let constr = MyFactory.buildTypeConstraints(this.model);
            if(!angular.equals(valueConstraints, constr)) valueConstraints= constr;
            return valueConstraints;
        } 
    },
    niveau: null
}];
```